# Should I make a compound index for this query?

Tags: mongodb, performance, indexing, database

Say I have a collection with 1 million documents like the ones below:

```
{
   email: "test@test.com",
   survey: ObjectId('whatever'),
   taken: Date(1/1/2015)
},
{
   email: "blah@blah.com",
   survey: ObjectId('whatever'),
   taken: Date(6/1/2015)
}
```

If I am going to going to execute a query like the one below fairly often:

```
db.participants.find({survey: ObjectId('whatever')}).sort({taken: 1})
```

How important is it for me to include `taken` in the index?  Typically the record set will go down from 1 million to about 30 based on the `survey` query and then those 30 records will be sorted.

Does it still make sense to index this column even though the filtered set that will be sorted is much smaller?

Comment: Including the `taken` field will make those queries more efficient (avoiding in-memory sort) but you'll have to measure the impact in your own environment. You could start by comparing the average execution time for your query with & without the extra field in the index but the real overhead will be seen in aggregate (i.e. depends on how many of these queries you are running, provisioning of your server environment, and interaction with your overall workload). It generally makes sense to have your common queries well indexed - consider the case when your ~30 records assumption is very low :)

Comment: I agree with @Stennie : this is very application-dependent. Assuming  ~30 records, the compound index here will speed up the sort, but will slow down inserts in you collection. Depending your use case, one or the other can prevail.

Comment: Is this estimate correct : an equality search in 1000000 indexed documents,  will take something like log2(1000000) = 19 comparisons. But the sort of 30 documents would take 30*log2(30) = 147 comparisons. Could someone confirm or infirm that, as I am not quite sure of those figures ?!?

Comment: It is to note that the slow down of the insert should be kind of negligible for such a small collection. As per my tests, other factors like other processes accessing the same disk and alike have a bigger impact. Therefor, as a rule of thumb: if in doubt, use an index.